# Dynamics 365 javascript validator

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

My question is about using dynamics 365 JavaScript validator on a Managed solution?
will it work on a Managed solution?

Comment: Which validator??

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `JavaScript Validator` and it only shows a log of all the API calls that will be deprecated along with their web resource name and line the code is on.

With this knowledge you can just run it on the managed solution and check

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/XrmToolBox.Dynamics365V9JavascriptValidator/

Comment: Can you include a link to the JavaScript Validator?

Comment: it is part of the XRMToolkit set of plugins; https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/XrmToolBox.Dynamics365V9JavascriptValidator/

Answer (score -1):

I hate to say that it probably will not matter as you would not be able to update the Managed Solution if it failed anyway. Since Managed Solutions uninstall cleanly, I would:

1.) Create a test environment at trials.dynamics.com then install the Solution.
2.) Test the Solution to see if it performs appropriately.
3.) Attempt to uninstall the Solution cleanly.

You should have your answer there.

Additionally, check with the Publisher to see if there are any updates. Hope that helps.